# Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference(NullpointerException)

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

Can anyone help? I've been trying to run a parallax image view in android studio but keep getting an exception message that states "Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference". It even clarifies that it is a NullPointerException. The message highlighted in blue where it seems to have occurred.

This is at line:

```
backgrounds.add(new Background(this.context, screenWidth, screenHeight, "skyline", 0, 80, 50));
```

in my ParallaxView class.

And at line:

```
setContentView(parallaxView);
```

in my ParallaxActivity class.

So, I expect this is where the exception occurs. I copied and pasted the full exception message and the classes below:

```
06-28 20:11:48.297 2420-2420/com.hfad.parallaxproject E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.hfad.parallaxproject, PID: 2420
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
ComponentInfo{com.hfad.parallaxproject/com.hfad.parallaxproject
.ParallaxActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: 
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference     
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)                                                                       
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: 
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.util.ArrayList.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference 
at com.hfad.parallaxproject.ParallaxView.<init>(ParallaxView.java:49) 
at com.hfad.parallaxproject.ParallaxActivity.onCreate(ParallaxActivity.java:25) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:111 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

These are the classes that the two errors occurred in:
1.

```
package com.hfad.parallaxproject;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ParallaxView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {

ArrayList<Background> backgrounds;

private volatile boolean running;
private Thread gameThread = null;

//For drawing
private Paint paint;
private Canvas canvas;
private SurfaceHolder ourHolder;

//Holds a reference to the Activity
Context context;

//Control the fps
long fps = 60;

//Screen resolution
int screenWidth;
int screenHeight;

ParallaxView(Context context, int screenWidth, int screenHeight) {
    super(context);

    this.context = context ;

    this.screenWidth = screenWidth;
    this.screenHeight = screenHeight;

    //Initialize our drawing objects
    ourHolder = getHolder();
    paint = new Paint();

    //load the background data into the Background objects and
    //place them in our GameObject arraylist

    backgrounds.add(new Background(this.context, screenWidth, screenHeight, "skyline", 0, 80, 50)) ;
    backgrounds.add(new Background(this.context, screenWidth, screenHeight, "grass", 70, 110, 200)) ;
    //Add more backgrounds here
}

private void drawBackground(int position) {

    //Make a copy of the relevant background
    Background bg = backgrounds.get(position) ;

    //define what portion of images to capture and
    //what coordinates of screen to draw them at

    //For the regular bitmap
    Rect fromRect1 = new Rect(0, 0, bg.width - bg.xClip, bg.height);
    Rect toRect1 = new Rect(bg.xClip, bg.startY, bg.width, bg.endY);

    //For the reversed background
    Rect fromRect2 = new Rect(bg.width - bg.xClip, 0, bg.width, bg.height);
    Rect toRect2 = new Rect(0, bg.startY, bg.xClip, bg.endY) ;

    //draw the two background bitmaps
    if(!bg.reversedFirst) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(bg.bitmap, fromRect1, toRect1, paint) ;
        canvas.drawBitmap(bg.bitmapReversed, fromRect2, toRect2, paint);
    } else {
        canvas.drawBitmap(bg.bitmap, fromRect2, toRect2, paint) ;
        canvas.drawBitmap(bg.bitmapReversed, fromRect1, toRect1, paint) ;
    }

}

@Override
public void run() {

    while(running) {
        long startFrameTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        update();

        draw();

        //Calculate the fps this frame
        long timeThisFrame = System.currentTimeMillis() - startFrameTime;
        if (timeThisFrame >= 1) {
            fps = 1000 / timeThisFrame;
        }
    }
}

private void update() {
    //Update all the background positions
    for(Background bg : backgrounds) {
        bg.update(fps) ;
    }
}

private void draw() {
    if(ourHolder.getSurface().isValid()) {
        //First we lock the area of memory we will be drawing to
        canvas = ourHolder.lockCanvas();

        //draw a background color
        canvas.drawColor(Color.argb(255, 0, 3, 70));

        //Draw the background parallax
        drawBackground(0) ;

        //Draw the rest of the game
        paint.setTextSize(60);
        paint.setColor(Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255));
        canvas.drawText("I am a plane", 350, screenHeight / 100 * 5, paint);
        paint.setTextSize(220);
        canvas.drawText("I'm a train", 50, screenHeight / 100 * 80, paint);

        drawBackground(1) ;
        //Draw the foreground parallax

        //Unlock and draw the scene
        ourHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }

}

//Clean up our thread if the game is stopped
public void pause() {
    running = false;
    try{
        gameThread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        //Error
    }
}

//Make a new thread and start it
//Execution moves to our run method

public void resume() {
    running = true;
    gameThread = new Thread(this);
    gameThread.start() ;
}
} //End of ParallaxView Class
```

And 
2.

```
package com.hfad.parallaxproject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Display;

public class ParallaxActivity extends Activity {

//Our object to handle the View
private ParallaxView parallaxView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Get a Display object to access screen details
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

    //Load the resolution into a Point object
    Point resolution = new Point();
    display.getSize(resolution);

    //And finally set the view for our game
    parallaxView = new ParallaxView(this, resolution.x, resolution.y);

    //Make our parallaxView the view for the Activity
    setContentView(parallaxView);
}

//If the Activity is paused make sure to pause our thread
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    parallaxView.pause();
}

//If the Activity is resumed make sure to resume our thread
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    parallaxView.resume();
}
}
```

Comment: initialize by `ArrayList<Background> backgrounds = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: Problem solved ! Thanks Sanoop, DeKaNszn, and GhostCat !

Answer (score 0):

You forget to initialize ArrayList.

```
ArrayList<Background> backgrounds = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Not my downvote; but an explanation: you probably dont know that basically all NPE questions get "duplicated" out quickly. Therefore answering them is more or less discouraged.